# How to control the confidence interval in autoplot.forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

After forecasting a time series, we can use autoplot to plot the time series, along with its predictions. I'm using the `forecast` package. But I want to control the confidence interval in the forecasted part. How do I make the plot show only 95% interval or only 80% interval, or not showing intervals at all. I set the argument `conf.int` to `FALSE`. But it does not seem to suppress the conf interval in the plot. Can anyone help to make it work? Thanks.

```
fc <- ses(AirPassengers, h = 5)
autoplot(fc, conf.int = F)
```

Answer (score 5):

The help files are very instructive. Read them. From `?forecast` you'll find this line:

> `level` 
>   Confidence level for prediction intervals.

and from `?autoplot.forecast` you will learn the following argument:

> `PI` 
>   Logical flag indicating whether to plot prediction intervals.

So you can do what you want as follows:

```
# Show 95% interval
fc <- ses(AirPassengers, h = 5, level=95)
autoplot(fc)
# Show no intervals
autoplot(fc, PI = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It does not work with survival (Surv) objects

Comment: I apologize. You are right Rob. The Documentation on the web is wrong. I followed Your advice and got the correct information with ?autoplot.survival.cox and that helped.

Comment: I think packages have been updated. This worked for me: `autoplot(fc, level = NULL)`. See https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/reference/autoplot.fbl_ts.html